# Help Solving System of Differential Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am working through some practice problems, and I am getting a different answer from what the back of my book says:

Express the general solution of the given system of equations in terms of real valued functions:

$$\begin{equation*}
x' = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -5 \\
1 & -2 \\
\end{pmatrix}x
\end{equation*}$$

I get eigenvalues of $$\pm i$$ and eigenvectors

$$\begin{equation*}
v_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2+i  \\
1  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$

$$\begin{equation*}
v_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2-i  \\
1  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$

The general solution with complex values is

$$\begin{equation*}
x = e^{it}
\begin{pmatrix}
2+i  \\
1  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$

which becomes

$$\begin{equation*}
x = (\cos(t)+i\sin(t))
\begin{pmatrix}
2+i  \\
1  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$

Expanding this and simplifying, I get

$$\begin{equation*}
x = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2\cos(t)-\sin(t)  \\
\cos(t)  \\
\end{pmatrix}
+ i
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(t)+2\sin(t)  \\
\sin(t)  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$

and then adding the constants, I get

$$\begin{equation*}
x = c_1
\begin{pmatrix}
2\cos(t)-\sin(t)  \\
\cos(t)  \\
\end{pmatrix}
+ c_2
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(t)+2\sin(t)  \\
\sin(t)  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$

which is my final answer.

Looking at the solution at the back of the book, it says the correct answer is

$$\begin{equation*}
x = c_1
\begin{pmatrix}
5\cos(t)  \\
2\cos(t)+\sin(t)  \\
\end{pmatrix}
+ c_2
\begin{pmatrix}
5\sin(t)  \\
-\cos(t)+2\sin(t)  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$

Where did I go wrong? Thank you.

Comment: What happened to $\pmatrix{2-i\\1}$?

Comment: Why do you think that your answer is different from the book?

Comment: change $c_1 \to 2a - b$ and $c_2 \to a + 2b$ in your solution (this is allowed since $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner , there is a theorem saying in the system $x'=Ax$, where each value of A is real and continuous, and if $x=u(t)+iv(t)$ is a complex solution of $x'=Ax$, then its real part $u(t)$ and imaginary part $v(t)$ are also solutions to the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{pmatrix} 2+i \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ is proportional to $\begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 2-i\end{pmatrix}$, so your solution is equivalent to the one given. You didn't do anything wrong.